# Oracle 11g XE Issues while Installing the database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle 11g XE successfully. I have applied the bash profile from the the oracle user (`source ~/.bash_profile`). It applied successfully. SQL*plus can also connect connected.

But whenever I type the `command lsnrctl status`, it shows no listener listening.
I am getting following ORA errors. I tried it every single solution from Google

```
ORA-12546: TNS: permission denied
TNS -12537: TNS connection closed
TNS -12560: TNS Adapter Error
TNS-00507: connection closed
Linux Error :29(Illegal Seek)
0RA- 27369 - Operation not Permitted
```

Comment: Are you logged in to Linux as `oracle`? Or another user?

Comment: i am logged into Linux as oracle